# VBA New Worksheet from a drop down list

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet with data from hospital patients from different health Authorities. I working with VBA and I am trying to create a macro that creates a new spreadsheet with only the data of the people belonging to that health authority. Health Authorities are identified with a number:

[image]

First I created a drop-down box containing the list of the health authorities. I have already created a button to insert the macro that I'm looking for. What I need to do now is write the VBA code that creates a sheet with only the selected Health Authority from the drop-down list.

This is what I came up with, but I think the whole code is incorrect.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Q42")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Range("Q42")
        Case "Insert Blank rows": Macro1
        Case "Hide All Sheets": Macro2
        Case "Convert to Date": Macro3
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

The name of the new sheet should be the name of the selected health authority.
The data collected is located in a sheet different to where i put the button: data is on the "data" sheet and the button is on the "user" sheet.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Just a heads-up: Worksheet names are restricted to 31 characters. Some of those authorities are going to cause an error.

Comment: Oh I see! How can I solve that?

Comment: Either rename the authorities - which you probably can't do, limit the sheet name to the first 31 characters in the authority name - probably not ideal, or use a look up table to convert the authority name into something that can be used as a sheet name.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given enough information to figure out how to filter the patient list for each authority.  This code is just how to create the worksheets in your file.

This code is based on selected authority ID's on a worksheet rather than a combo or list box.
I've also used a lookup table to rename your authorities if needed.  You only need to list the authorities that need renaming.  If the replacement name isn't in the list it will use the original.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    'HARange are the selected cells in your Health Authority Range.
    Dim HARange As Range
    Set HARange = Selection
    
    'Create a new workbook with a single sheet.
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    
    'Look at each cell in your selection.
    Dim Itm As Range
    For Each Itm In HARange
    
        'Create a new worksheet and store its reference in the wrkSht variable.
        Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
        Set wrkSht = wrkBk.Worksheets.Add
        
        'Rename the worksheet and move it to the end.
        With wrkSht
            .Name = ReplacementName(Itm) 'Pass the cell to the ReplacementName function.
            .Move After:=wrkBk.Worksheets(wrkBk.Worksheets.Count)
        End With
    Next Itm
    
    'Providing new sheets were created in the new workbook then
    'delete the first (blank) worksheet.
    'DisplayAlerts are disabled so it quietly deletes the sheet
    'rather than warning you about it first.
    If wrkBk.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wrkBk.Worksheets(1).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
End Sub

'Find the Authority ID in the lookup table and return the value to the right of it.
'If it's not found return the original authority name instead.
Private Function ReplacementName(AuthorityID As Range) As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
        Dim rFound As Range
        Set rFound = .ListColumns("ID").Range.Find(What:=AuthorityID, _
                                                   After:=.ListColumns("ID").Range.Cells(1), _
                                                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                   LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                   SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            ReplacementName = rFound.Offset(, 1)
        Else
            ReplacementName = AuthorityID.Offset(, 1)
        End If
        
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. However I have a question; is Table 1 inside the data sheet or am I supposed to create a separate sheet?

Comment: You can have it on the same sheet or a different one - update the sheet name it looks at in the line `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")`.  `ThisWorkbook` is a reference to the workbook containing the code.  You can also rename the table - a `Table` menu should appear on the Excel ribbon when you select a cell in the table and can rename it in there.